# MySQL Stored Procedure Unexpected Behaviour in certain conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am relatively new to MySQL stored Procedures. I have a stored procedure that works fine in certain conditions and not in other. I'm a bit confused that what causes the error. It is a entity processing SP, based on certain values and conditions it either creates or update entity from data in a staging table.

In conditions when it works fine:

1. When I only process a single entity.
2. Works for bulk entries when there is nothing in `entity` table.

Don't works when:

1. There are entries in `entity` table and bulk processing is done. - Error in checking up the already existing `entity_id` in `entity` and older `entity_id` is assigned instead a new one should be created.

(I actually need above scenario to work more frequently than others)

I have tried to keep the code to minimum in order to understand the flow of SP. Please consider all variables as declared. *SP might not compile.*

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_ent`(test_id int)
BEGIN
    -- Move code tables to temp tables
    -- Declare all the required variables here
    DECLARE counter, len INT;
    DECLARE var2 INT;
    DECLARE var3 TINYINT(1);
    DECLARE var4 DECIMAL(18,4);
    DECLARE var5 DATE;
    DECLARE var6 VARCHAR(1000);
    DECLARE var7 VARCHAR(5000);

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `temp_ent`;
    IF test_id IS NOT NULL THEN
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `temp_ent` AS (SELECT * FROM `ent_st` WHERE processed = 0 and id=test_id);
    ELSE
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `temp_ent` AS (SELECT * FROM `ent_st` WHERE processed = 0);
    END IF;
    ALTER TABLE `temp_ent` ADD PRIMARY KEY(id);
    -- SELECT * FROM `temp_ent`;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `temp_exc`; CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `temp_exc` AS (SELECT * FROM `code_exc`);
    -- A few more like above

    SET counter=1, len=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `temp_ent`);
    WHILE counter <= len DO

        SELECT `id`,var1, var2, var3
        INTO v_id,var1, var2, var3
        FROM `temp_ent` LIMIT 1;-- WHERE `id` = v_id;

        BEGIN
        DECLARE insufficient_information CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '45000';
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR insufficient_information SET v_proccessed=1;

        SET v_status = CASE 
            WHEN ... THEN ...
            ELSE 'valid'
        END;

        IF v_status <> 'valid' THEN SIGNAL insufficient_information; END IF;

        SELECT `entity_id`,`entity` 
        INTO v_underlying_entity_id,v_underlying_entity_symbol
        FROM `entity` WHERE `entity_id` = v_underlying OR `entity` = v_underlying_entity;
        SET v_underlying_entity_symbol = COALESCE(v_underlying_entity_symbol,v_underlying_entity);

        SET v_entity = (
        CASE 
            WHEN ... THEN ...
            WHEN ... THEN ...
            .
            .
            WHEN ... THEN ...
        END
        );

        SELECT `entity_id`,`entity`
        INTO v_entity_id_check,v_entity_check
        FROM entity WHERE `entity`=v_entity and `exc`=v_exc;

        -- SELECT v_entity_id_check,v_entity_check,v_entity,v_exc;
        IF v_entity_check IS NULL THEN
            -- SELECT 'Create New Entity and Add';
            SET v_entity_id = COALESCE((SELECT MAX(`entity_id`) FROM entity),0) + 1;
            SET new_entity = 1;
        ELSE 
            -- SELECT 'Entity Already Present'; 
            SET v_entity_id = v_entity_id_check; 
            SET new_entity = 0;
        END IF;
        -- SELECT v_entity_id, v_entity, new_entity;

        SET v_name = UPPER(COALESCE(v_name,v_entity));
        -- UPDATE entity and underlying/derivatives table
        IF new_entity = 1 THEN

            -- Insert in respective tables
            IF ... THEN
                -- SELECT 'Entity Added',v_entity; -- Underlying Entity
                INSERT INTO `entity_underlying` (`entity_id`,`entity`,`name`,`exc`,`seg`,`ins`,`isin`,`fo_yn`,`tick`,`lot_size`,`active_yn`) 
                VALUES (v_entity_id,v_entity,v_name,v_exc,v_seg,v_ins,COALESCE(v_isin,''),COALESCE(v_fo_yn,0),COALESCE(v_tick,0.05),COALESCE(v_lot_size,1),1); 
            ELSEIF ... THEN
                -- SELECT 'Entity Added',v_entity; -- Derivative Entity
                INSERT INTO `entity_derivatives` (`entity_id`,`entity`,`name`,`underlying`,`exc`,`seg`,`ins`,`ser`,`isin`,`strike`,`tick`,`lot_size`,`expiry`,`ex_ty`,`active_yn`) 
                VALUES (v_entity_id,v_entity,v_name,COALESCE(v_underlying_entity_id,-1),v_exc,v_seg,v_ins,COALESCE(v_ser,''),v_isin,COALESCE(v_strike),COALESCE(v_tick,0.05),COALESCE(v_lot_size,-1),v_expiry,v_ex_ty,1); 
            END IF;
            -- Insert in final table
            INSERT INTO entity(`entity_id`,`entity`,`exc`,`active_yn`) 
            VALUES (v_entity_id,v_entity,v_exc,1);

            SET v_status='Entity Added';
        ELSE
            SET v_status='Not a New Entity';
        END IF;

     END;

        UPDATE `ent_st` SET `entity_id`=v_entity_id,`processed`=1,`status`=v_status WHERE id=v_id;

        DELETE FROM `temp_ent` WHERE id=v_id; 

        SET counter = counter +1;
        COMMIT;
    END WHILE;
END
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i doubt that anybody can help with that complex procedures, but you have a simple debugging problem and that is with big procedures tedious, but get with user defined variables the data that is processed and see if the query runs out side

Comment: Actually I tried debugging by Getting data out in each loop iteration and when I do that then even procedure works as expected. I'm not sure how to debug it more efficiently. Are there any tools that can help me with that or any other way of debugging ?

Comment: I have activated general log and binlog so that i can see every query that runs and see so if something unexpected happens. but basically no, you to come up with the same scenario that happens and couses the problem as i said tedious work

Comment: @ap14 . . . I don't even know what "bulk processing" is supposed to mean.  You need to learn how to debug your own code -- by running it step by step, by putting in breakpoints, and so on.

Comment: If you look at the procedure then you will see if the procedure parameter is passed as NULL then it will process all available entries otherwise only for the id passed.